# Bootstrap 4 modal with iframe - border of modal is not shown correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Datatables and I am calling a modal there where an iFrame is displayed. However, the loading of the iFrame takes time and the border of the modal is not adjusted. I tried  `$('#myiModal').modal('handleUpdate')` but it does not bring the desired effect.

Here is a simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/knpcdhf6/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was, you gave **`iframe`** a **`position absolute`** . I think u did that to adjust the padding. To remove padding you can use **`p-0`** class to **`modal-body`**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //myiModal
  $('#details').on('click', 'button.showimodal', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).data("href") + "?" + Date.now();
    console.log('show imodal');
    //console.log(url);
    $("#myiModal iframe").attr("src", url);
    $("#myiModal").modal("show");
  });

  //onclose reset iframe
  $("#myiModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).find('iframe').html("").attr("src", "");
    console.log('modalclosed');
  });

});
```

```css
.modal-content {
    border: 10px solid rgb(255 4 4 / 80%)!important;

}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- iframemodal -->
  <div class="modal fade dtr-bs-modal" id="myiModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Title</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body p-0
        ">

          <iframe id="modaliframe" class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" width="100%"  style=""></iframe>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end iframemodal -->


  <div class="container">

    <span id="details">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary showimodal" data-href="https://orf.at/">iModal 1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary showimodal" data-href="https://overclockers.at/">iModal 2</button>
    </span>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and solution, I was not aware that `position absolute` triggered my problem. Yes, that was to adjust the padding to position the iframe at the very edge. `p-0` is of course also the more elegant solution.